# Stata Multiple Imputation output file

Tags: file, stata

I'm new to Stata. I need to implement multiple imputation on Stata, but I have a problem when using it. I do everything like instruction by the following codes:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r11/mheart1s20
mi describe
mi impute regress bmi attack smokes age female hsgrad, add(20)
```

Then I got every thing as in instruction. However, I want to find the out put file (completed data).

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. This outputs a table on the screen. What output file are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate output data file; the 'completed' data is in memory. If you do `mi describe` again, you'll see that the dataset in memory now contains *M* = 40 imputations, whereas the output from the previous `mi describe` showed it contained *M* = 20 imputations. So you have added 20 imputations to the dataset, as specified by the `add(20)` option to your `mi impute` command.